# Can I pre-check bit-bucket pull-requests for code style?

Tags: bitbucket

Lately I've been getting a number of pull requests for some projects that don't meet the code style guidelines (bad formatting, missing documentation, etc).

Is there any way in Bitbucket to enforce that any new pull-request must pass a certain validation script or code-style enforcer or something like that?

I could not find anything related to this in the Atlassian docs.

Answer (score 1):

The closes thing to what you want that I have come across is this plugin: https://github.com/reconquest/atlassian-external-hooks

It let's you run a bash script on the host machine that Bitbucket is running on, and based on the result accept/reject the commit. You have to install the style checker on your system and write the script yourself, but there is an example in the [docs](https://external-hooks.reconquest.io/docs/example.bitbucket-add_hook_javascript_linter/) that should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

You could trigger a build on the Pull Request (which could be done automatically when a pull request is raised). This build would be configured with all the checks you referred to. If there is anything wrong with the code under the pull request, the build fails!

You could configure BitBucket pull requests to be 'merge-able' only when the build succeeds.

Comment: This answer doesn't provide any information related to the question (how to enforce that any new pull-request must pass a certain validation script or code-style enforcer).